# Android web view blank page

Tags: android, webview

I searched for two days for a solution - including all stackover posts - and couldn't solve it ..

My web view can open sites like Google and Facebook but can't open the site in the code !

here is my full code

```
 webView = findViewById(R.id.wv_pray_time);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://ramadanco.noursal.com/");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        // No net error
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }
        });

        // Pull to refresh
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webView.reload();
                        if (mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `error.html` file located in your project, and what are its contents?

Comment: it is in assets folder and have a simple html code with error message ... !

Comment: still can't solve it .. can anyone open this site inside a webview ?